# Why does Dagger 2 force me to use @Provides instead of @Binds

Tags: java, dagger-2

I am looking into Dagger 2 (Java) right now and came across an issue right upon the start. Sadly, I was not able find a anything yet in the Dagger 2 Documentation or on Stackoverflow about it, so if you guys know some resources I would really appreciate it.

I prepared a minimal example within this repository here to explain whats my issue: https://github.com/stackoverflow-samples/dagger2-dependency-cycle

So we got an **Application** class that should be constructed

```
public class Application {

    @Inject
    public Application(SomeDependency one) {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DaggerApplicationComponent.create().build();
    }
}
```

... with a dummy dependency

```
public class SomeDependency {

    @Inject
    public SomeDependency() {

    }
}
```

And of course the Dagger classes/interfaces ...
.. a component interface:

```
@Component(modules = ApplicationModule.class)
public interface ApplicationComponent {
    Application build();
}
```

.. and a module:

```
@Module
abstract class ApplicationModule {
    @Provides
    static SomeDependency provideDepdendencyOne() {
        return new SomeDependency();
    }
}
```

What I dont get is why Dagger forces me to register `SomeDepdendency` with `@Provides` annotation and does not allow to register it via `@Binds`:

```
@Binds 
abstract SomeDependency bindDepdendencyOne(SomeDependency one);
```

Whenever I change the code from `@Provides` to `@Binds` it gives me the following errors:

```
[Dagger/DependencyCycle] Found a dependency cycle:
      io.github.codejanovic.dagger2.example.SomeDependency is injected at
          io.github.codejanovic.dagger2.example.ApplicationModule.bindDepdendencyOne(one)
      io.github.codejanovic.dagger2.example.SomeDependency is injected at
          io.github.codejanovic.dagger2.example.Application(one)
      io.github.codejanovic.dagger2.example.Application is provided at
          io.github.codejanovic.dagger2.example.ApplicationComponent.build()
```

Being unable to `@Bind` an implementation makes absolutely no sense to me. What do I oversee?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're wrong in assuming that you need `@Binds` or `@Provides` in the first place. You can and should be using constructor injection—not the pattern, but the *Dagger generates the code for me* kind.

You already have the constructor annotated with `@Inject`, thus Dagger knows about the class and how to create it. There's nothing else to do.

```
public class SomeDependency {

    @Inject
    public SomeDependency() {

    }
}
```

You don't need any `@Provides`, no `@Binds`, not even a `@Module` for this simple use case of yours. Your example should work right out of the box since both constructors are annotated with `@Inject`.

```
@Component
public interface ApplicationComponent {
    Application build();
}
```

If you need to specify a scope you can add it on the class.

---

`@Provides` should be used for code that you can't use constructor injection for, or that needs additional setup. Of course you can create all the objects manually (as you're doing in your example) but this has no real benefit and will just produce a lot of boilerplate that can be avoided.

`@Binds` is to be used with implementations that you need to bind to an interface. Optimally you'd use constructor injection for the implementation as well, but you can as well add it to the component builder (`@BindsInstance`) or create it in a `@Provides` annotated method.

```
@Binds MyInterface bindMyImplementation(MyImplementation implementation);
```

Answer (score 1):

If your class is marked with an `@Inject` constructor:

```
public class SomeDependency {

    @Inject // <----
    public SomeDependency() {

    }
}
```

Then you need `@Binds` (or `@Provides`) only if you need to "bind" it as an implementation of an interface, or at least a different type than its concrete type.

Also, if your object has an `@Inject` constructor, you would not need to instantiate it in the module, because Dagger already knows how to instantiate it.

So to fix your code, all you need to do is:

```
// @Module
// abstract class ApplicationModule {
//     @Provides
//     static SomeDependency provideDepdendencyOne() {
//         return new SomeDependency();
//     }
// }
```

Solved.

Comment: Oh my ... thats what I missed, thanks guys! Coming from Guice i thought the declaration is required!